# How to change iframes src with same classes, names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<iframe id="chgMe" src="Source1.htm">Frames are not supported on your browser.</iframe>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgMe').src='Source2.htm'">Next</button>
```

It works good, but when generates 2 or more iframes with same id, second, third, fourth etc. iframes not respond. I tried `document.getElementByTagName();` and `document.getElementByName();` but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiple elements with same `id` is not allowed.

```
<button id="change_src">Next</button>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#change-src').on('click', function() {
  $('#chgMe').attr('src', 'Source2.htm?' + (new Date()).getTime();
});
```

---

You can maintain a patter for you `id` like: `chgMe_1, chgMe_2` and so on and modify you code like below:

```
$('#change-src').on('click', function() {
  $('[id*=chgMe_]').attr('src', 'Source2.htm?' + (new Date()).getTime();
});
```

which will select all `iframe`s of `id` contains `chgMe_`.

---

Or, alternatively you can use a common `class` for all `iframe` and use that like following:

```
$('#change-src').on('click', function() {
  $('.common_cls_name').attr('src', 'Source2.htm?' + (new Date()).getTime();
});
```

#### Note

`(new Date()).getTime()` is for just prevent the cache and all above codes will change the `src` of all `iframe`*(according to your question)*.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a function for creating a new iframe (if you didn't already), give each of them the id chgMe0, chgMe1, chgMe2, ... and then call another function when clicking the "Next" button, that does something like this:

```
var framecount; // global variable that counts all frames

function next(nextpage)
{
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<framecount;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("chgMe"+i).src=nextpage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute must be unique, use classes instead, or generate new IDs as you add the IFrames.